I want to make an image of a car constantly move right with this code but it doesn't work. How do I fix it?
   var Car = function (x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };

    Car.prototype.draw = function () {
        var carhtml = '<img src ="https://nostarch.com/images/car.png">';

        this.carElement = $(carhtml)

        this.carElement.css({
            position: "absolute",
            left: this.x,
            top: this.y
        });

        $("body").append(this.carElement);
    }

   Car.prototype.moveRight = function () {
        this.x += 5;

        this.carElement.css({
            position: "absolute",
            left: this.x,
            top: this.y
        });
    };


    var tesla = new Car(10, 20)
   

    tesla.draw()


    setInterval(tesla.moveRight, 20)

I want an image ot a car to move 5 pixels right every 20 miliseconds using setInterval.
I get this error every time I launch the code:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'css')
at Car.moveR (edu2.html:61:29)

Try window.setInterval(() => tesla.moveRight(), 20);

It worked, thanks @0stone0
